# Has anyone got any experience developing a site based on WebQuarters?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, content-management-system

I'm in the process of planning out a site for a friend, they need to be able to modify site content, have a products section and shopping/ check-out area. All the products need to be able to be updatable too (descriptions, photos, cost - including delivery, etc).

As I'm a bit of an ASP.NET MVC fanboy currently, I was going to build a quick CMS in my spare time, however, a friend just pointed me at [WebQuarters](http://www.openquarters.org/site/webquarters) - an open source MVC based CMS.

So, my question is this - given the requirements, does it make more sense to build on top of WebQuarters or go my own route?

Additionally, does anyone have any experience of using WebQuarters...is it any good or should I steer clear?

Thanks,
Kieron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been looking at this as well and trying to see how suitable it will be for a similar project I will be starting soon. So far it looks good, but some of the admin parts when your editing your pages don't feel quite as solid (like editing the menu order).

I'm keeping an eye on it though, I think it will be a great library to add to your tool chest.

Comment: Good comments, thanks. There doesn't appear to be much community interest (or maybe knowledge) in WQ currently. Seems a shame.